# How can I get e-mailed when the Apple Developer Program License Agreement gets updated?

Tags: ios, developer-program, license

I get lots of e-mail from Apple about WWDC and other advertisements (hey, we've just added 16 countries to the store), which act as clues that the ADPLA has or is about to update. But nothing explicit.

Surest way is to log into developer.apple.com on a daily basis and look for an alert.

Is there a setting in the Apple Developer site to get these notifications?

Is there a third party site or mailing list that keeps track of these changes?

Comment: Seems to be a common issue with lots of companies (inc my power supplier).  I've reached the point where my next free time project is to create a web scraper to keep track on these sites for changes...

Comment: Unfortunately, with Apple, you have to be logged into to scrape that page, and with 2 factor, it's a pain in the butt.